# swift массив не получает значения во втором контроллере

Tags: массивы, swift

Есть два контроллера MapViewController и TracksViewController.

В MapVC создан массив testArray.
В TracksVC создана сущность let mc = MapViewController()

В функции идет запись в этот массив:
mc.testArray.append(blablabla)

При этом массив прирастает только в TracksVC, система видит что переменная растет.
А вот в MapVC он как был нулевым так и остается.

Что  делаю не так?

Comment: Прошу принять мои извинения, но пользователя данного сайта не могут видеть файлы на вашем личном пк, и прошу вас добавить тут ваш код что-бы мы могли ваш помочь ^-^

Comment: Вам нужно не создавать MapViewController, а например передавать ссылку на него, но лучше использовать механизм делегатов например, чтобы не связывать жестко вью контроллеры, почитайте на тему передачи данных между вью контроллерами